# Multiple MVC projects in a solution with common layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have searched and looked around for possible solutions, but have not found it. Basically there's a need for us to have multiple projects in a solution, since most of our mvc apps use common library such as AD authentication, SQL objects. And we want all our mvc web app to have a common layout. below are some of the possible solution proposed by others I've seen online:

1. Area - it is nice, does almost what I wanted except it compiles into one single dll. The reason why I prefer multiple projects is that each team can work on certain project compile into its own dll and will not affect the overall application.
2. Razor generator - I tested this out. I could be wrong, but this tool is used mainly for sharing views/controllers across projects. I don't think this applies to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Put the common layout in a NuGet package and install the package in all the projects that want to use it.

Comment: I'm unsure of your question. Yes, you can have multiple projects in your solution.. I've done this on a team where we had separate projects (and DLLs) for domain objects, payment/accounting, custom UI controls, data layer, etc.

Comment: Razor generator can be used for any view and for Layout also. @SamLeach, Could you provide an example of usage NuGet packge within single one solution for sharing common code?

Comment: I think you're looking at this backwards.  You don't want multiple MVC projects in one solution, You want Multiple solutions, each with it's own MVC project, using a shared set of projects for your common layout.  This keeps each MVC site separated.

Comment: @Smith - I wanted to know if we can have multiple MVC web projects and have common layout. What you said sounded like you only have 1 MVC web projects and other common library code project such as domain objects, payment/accounting....

Comment: @ErikTheViking - yes originally that's what we thought of. But each of these mvc solutions will have their own copy of the same common layout,css,images - master page.

Comment: @user1784014 - Umm.. And?  Sharing the same layout does not mean they have to be in the same solution.

Comment: @ErikTheViking - so when there's changes need to be done on the common layout, you would have to go to each individual solution and copy the new changes? This is the whole reason why I wanted to know if there's a better approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple mvc project in solution just for separating them for teams is not a good idea as you will have to add lot's of configuration both in development process and deployment. as you mentioned the first solution is better. but I suggest you to use portable areas of mvc if you really want to separate the concerns of your team working and don't need multiple standalone mvc project. you can embed a _layout in a core class library (a core assembly for all the common configurations of your areas) and reference all of the ares.